# Auto generated unique number column on each update

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 5 + Entity Framework 6. Suppose I have this model:

```
public class ModelName
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UniqueColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want the `UniqueColumn` to be updated whenever I use `db.SaveChangesAsync();` (meaning on both `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s).

I tried to use `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` but it won't update after the insert. I tried setting it to 0 but it gives me an error indicating that I can't modify an `Identity` column.

Comment: just a little searching here, showed a lot of related q&a... Do you have mapping set up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905268/entity-framework-does-not-update-an-auto-increment-field-of-a-computed-key-in-my

Comment: @kenny hmm. I don't have any experience with that mapping stuff but I'm not sure it's related. (maybe I'm wrong). The question seems to be looking for a primary key column. I just want a unique code for each record but it should change whenever the record is updated.

Comment: do you want some thing like a                                                   [Timestamp]
public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "to be updated"? You need to make it +1 on each action?
IF that is the case, try to make it static and access by class name, so it will not depend on object of this class. After update or insert action just do

```
ModelName.UniqueColumn++;
```

Comment: BTW it's not static. I want a unique value for each record.

Comment: I don't know what exacly you need to have in this variable. If this is Unique ID value, you can do this:
You could create additional variable, which will get last ID number from your database. This should be static. Let say this will be static field in class named LastID Then you can do something like this:
ModelName.LastID++
newRecord.UniqueColumn = LastID

To get LastID, just sort your list by ID and take List.Last().Id